# Codenvy with Gradle for Android

Tags: android, maven, gradle, cloud, codenvy

Tried to use [Codenvy](https://codenvy.io) cloud IDE and found it as promising.

Still there're some issues/questions: particularly area of my interests is Android development and de-facto industry standard for Android development is Gradle. Unfortunately (for sure fortunately for maven supporters) Codenvy lacks Gradle support.

I do have large enough project, which is completely under Gradle.

Question: how to enable Gradle support within Codenvy?

P.S. I do not plan to explode my own private cloud with Eclipse Che - Codenvy is enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse Che as of right now does not appear to have full out-of-the-box Gradle support, yet; read (and watch) [Che Issue 2669](https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/2669) for full details.

Answer (score 0):

Codenvy is based on Eclipse Che and there's a tutorial on the Che docs about using Gradle: https://eclipse-che.readme.io/docs/che-and-gradle

You can duplicate the Android stack and add Gradle to it (https://eclipse-che.readme.io/docs/stacks#section-duplicate-a-stack). Then add commands as shown in the tutorial.